# Can't run Netbeans php project without Android SDK

Tags: php, android, netbeans-8

I've been developing a php program on windows 10 using Netbeans 8.0.  Today, for some reason, Netbeans gives an Error - Android Platform is not configured.  Tried unsuccessfully installing the Android Studio. Can I run Netbeans without it?

Comment: Actually, I using Apache Netbeans 12.5, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

My browser was accidently set to Android device which demanded an Android SDK.
Setting browser to Firefox fixed the problem.